# Most Standard/Common Way to Make HTTP Requests in Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, httprequest

Hey I'm new to Android and am working on a basic Android app that is trying to connect to a MYSQL db through PHP scripts. So, I need to access this PHP by making HTTP Requests. The tutorial I was following along with recommended to make a JSON Parser class in java which makes use of the deprecated DefaultHTTPClient and Asynctask. Apparently there is something called httpurlconnection which I think does the same thing as httpclient. There's also the Volley library which apparently is "faster."

I was wondering, what is the recommended practice for my scenario? Right now I'm just working on login/register part of the app.

Comment: Use `HttpURLConnection` in an `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 1):

There is too many third party libraries available for network operations :

Here is some recommendation :

1. [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) by Google
2. [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) by squre

[Here](http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/) is also comparison for performance of both of this libraries.
Choose one according to your requirement.

Hope it will helps.!!

Answer (score 0):

Inside your main activity of your application put the below.

You need to run the network requests on another thread you cannot run them on the main thread. Use HttpURLConnection to make connections with servers and rest of the code i have written. Once the response is recieved from the server the handlers can be used to show the response on the main thread.

```
 Handler mHandle = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public  void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            String data = (String) msg.obj;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),data,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //show the response recieved from the server
        }
    };

    Handler mHandle2 = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public  void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            String data = (String) msg.obj;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"This is a handler2 here so please ignore this test here to test the functionality",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

 public void send(View v)
    {

        final ContentValues  values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("data1", "Stackoverflow answer :)");

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    final URL url = new URL("http://example.com/resp.php");
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    con.setDoOutput(true);
                    con.setDoInput(true);
                    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    String parameters = "data1=" + URLEncoder.encode("SOMETHING", "UTF-8");
                    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" +
                            Integer.toString(parameters.getBytes().length));
                    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
                    con.setUseCaches(false);
                    con.setRequestProperty("Charset", "UTF-8");
                    OutputStream OS = con.getOutputStream() ;
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS,"UTF-8"));
                    writer.write(parameters);
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
                    int statuscode = con.getResponseCode();
                    BufferedInputStream bufstream = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
                    byte[] somedata = new byte[1024];
                    int byteRead = 0;
                    String datahere = "",temp= "";
                    while(  (byteRead = bufstream.read(somedata)) != -1 )
                    {
                         /* read(byte[] buffer, int byteOffset, int byteCount)
                        Reads up to byteCount bytes from this stream and stores them in the byte array buffer starting at byteOffset. */
                        temp = new String(somedata,0,byteRead);
                        datahere = datahere+temp;
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),datahere,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    Message msg=new Message();
                    Message msg2=new Message();
                    msg.obj=datahere;
                    mHandle.sendMessage(msg);
                    msg2.obj="This is just a test";
                    mHandle2.sendMessage(msg2);
                }  catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("ReleaseInfo", "JSoup get didnt get a document", e);
                }

            }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start(); //Network request do not run on the main thread so run it on another thread

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I provide one **solution** for you.
>
> I wrote a project ([EocboxVolleyBox](https://github.com/CloudedDragon/eocboxVolleyBox)) to show how to get the JSON from internet and save it in the Java Object with **Gson**, **Volley**, and **OkHttp**.
>
> **EocboxVolleyBox** is a toolbox for integration of Android Volley library, OkHttp and Gson.